# Shopify Custom Node App - Responding to Order Create Event

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm working on a private node-based application which will interact with the store whenever a new order is created.

What I'd like to do is modify the data, specifically the `order.note` attribute.

Is a 'webhook' the right tool for this task? If so, can one elaborate what type of JavaScript one needs for this? I'm using the `shopify-node-api` package.

Comment: Please provide additional information about the use case

Comment: I would like to modifiy the ```order.note``` based on data present in query string from ```order.landing_site```. I would like to run this logic on every new order that comes in, automatically.